# Removing white bars imshow matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I am trying to create a side-by-side plot containing a heatmap directly next to a curve.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 1, sharey = True, gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios': [3, 1]})
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

im = ax1.imshow(data1, cmap='gist_rainbow', interpolation='nearest', aspect = 'auto')

ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.plot(sums, data2, color = 'red')
ax2.scatter(sums, data2, c='k')
```

`data1` is a (297, 15) numpy array, `sums` and `data2` are (1, 15).

Using the above results in the following plot, which has annoying white bars on the top and bottom of the `imshow`, which I *cannot* get rid of. What can I do to make them go away?

[image: sharey = True]

Comment: Have you tried setting the y-axis limits manually?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: For reference if anyone has this same problem, I set `sharey = False`, and added a line `ax2.set_ylim([-0.5,14.5])`.

Comment: There is also `ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)`